# Correct way to post a YouTube video on Facebook

Tags: facebook, youtube

I seem to remember posting links to YouTube videos and having Facebook show it as an embedded video.   Recently, when I tried the same, it displayed the link without embedding the video.   Is there a way to have Facebook display YouTube videos as embedded videos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be doing something wrong, here's the right way to share YouTube videos on Facebook wall, go to that video page on YouTube that you want to share, then click on **Share** button, you'll see a Facebook icon there, click on that icon, a small pop up window will open, Facebook will ask your login details, if you are already logged in Facebook then you'll see  your video embedded in a post, just give a title to your post and then you'll see your video posted on your wall rather than links :)

Comment: Thanks, that works.  It even let me include the video on the wall of a page I own.    I didn't see a way to attach it to an Event, though.

Comment: You are welcome, and for the events, you should be able to post the YouTube video link onto the event page (if the admin has posted links enabled).