# How to post embedded YouTube video on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, youtube, embed

In the past, when I shared a YouTube link, it was showing as embedded content. Which allowed the user to watch the video from within Facebook.

Now, when I share a YouTube link it doesn't embed it anymore (only in comments).

**Is there anyway to share the YouTube video as embedded content on Facebook?**

---

*I checked [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19806/correct-way-to-post-a-youtube-video-on-facebook) and the suggested solution is similar to what I used to do before - but it's 7 years old, so it makes sense that a lot has changed since then.*

Comment: Simply use the URL 
    
https://shareme.pro/youtube/VideoID 

for sharing on Facebook where VideoID is the ID of your video.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Facebook changed its behavior, and it's no longer possible** - all links, including videos, will be opened externally, to mirror the mobile experience.

From a [*Bug Info* found on **facebook for developers**](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1963535797258090/):

> *Reply from* **Spencer Hitchcock | Facebook Team** 
>   ...
>
> It looks like this behavior is actually by design.
>
> In our efforts to make News Feed an even more visual and engaging place to connect, we have been introducing **new design updates in News Feed beginning in August 2017.**
>
> As part of these updates and to provide a consistent experience across desktop and mobile, **external video link posts** (both paid and organic) on desktop will **look and function similar to other link posts**. **People will now tap on the links to go off of Facebook to watch videos** instead of watching within News Feed — mirroring the experience available for such posts on mobile.
>   
> ...

Answer (score 4):

Facebook has been getting serious with their video efforts in the past couple months, launching some critical features for video creators, as well as getting exclusive contracts with big media event organizers.

In the past, Facebook already changed the way YouTube embeds are displayed from a large to a small view, which prompted third party websites to pop up to bring large thumbnails

[image: example of a third party website generating a large thumbnail]

There is [**One Other Method**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/116453/how-to-post-embedded-youtube-video-on-facebook/130715#130715) where you can **embed and play Youtube videos on Facebook** (viewable on all devices including mobile and tablets)

In any case, the following options don't seem to work anymore:

- Link to `youtube.com/watch?v=VideoID`, `youtube.com/embed/VideoID`, `youtu.be/VideoID`, `youtube.com/v/VideoID`
- Links to the numerous third party websites embedding YouTube (the larger thumbnails do still work though)
- Sharing via the Facebook button in YouTube itself

Answer (score -4):

**FULL STEP-BY-STEP INSTRUCTIONS WITH SCREENSHOTS AND WORKING EXAMPLES**

**[Full Step by Step Guide and Working Example](https://s.nari.co.za/2U)**

I've searched the internet and spend hours watching 100's of videos but all turned out to be either not working or outdated.

With Facebook being the biggest social media platform, what is better than having your Youtube videos Embedded right into Facebook platform.

**NO APPS REQUIRED**

Everyone would be able to watch your Youtube Videos on Facebook. No need to follow a link to Youtube - and all devices can watch your videos - mobile devices and tablets included!

I will also show you how to **Embed Multiple Youtube Videos into One single Facebook Post** (and all of them are perfectly embedded and viewable on Facebook)!

**MONETIZED?**

By using my method to embed your Youtube videos into Facebook, Google Adsense Ads will also be displayed right there.

**Please Note:**
There's only one downside or limitation and that is: Facebook don't allow you to create this type of post using a tablet or mobile device - you can **only create this type of post using a desktop computer.**

This would also apply should you want to edit the post in the future - You can view the post on any device but you can not create or edit this type of post on mobile or tablet devices. Let's get Started!

**Step-by-Step Instructions:**

**How to Embed one or Multiple Youtube Videos into One Facebook Post:**

**Step 1:** Go to your Youtube Channel or to any other Youtube Channel and open the video that you want to Embed into Facebook.

**Step 2:** Click the Video URL located in the browser right at the top of your screen and copy the url.

[image]

**Step 3:** Now go to your Facebook profile and from the horizontal menu bar, hover or click on the More dropdown section. In the dropdown list, look for Notes and open it.

[image]

**Step 4:** Now click on the + Add Note button to create a new note.

[image]

**Step 5:** Now you can Upload a Cover or Feature Image right at the top and give your note a Title. In the next step is where all the Magic happens.

[image]

**Step 6:** After you've uploaded a Cover image and given your Note a Title, click your mouse cursor on the "Write something..." text below the title. Now move your mouse cursor to the left and hover over the + icon. A pop-up window will appear with 2 options: Photo or Embed. Click on Embed.

**Step 7:** After you clicked on Embed, a window will open. Now paste the Video URL that you copied right in the beginning of this tutorial. Note: If your paste doesn't work, then you have to go copy the Video URL from your Youtube browser again.

**Step 8 (VERY IMPORTANT):** After you've pasted the URL you will have to make the following changes to the URL. Look at the URL. Remove **watch** and Replace it with **embed** and click Insert.

[image]

Your Youtube video should now be Embedded into Facebook. You can add multiple Youtube Videos into One post.

**YOUTUBE PARTNER PROGRAM**

If you're accepted into the Youtube Partner Program and your Channel is approved for monetization, you will also see your Google Adsense Ads in the embedded videos on Facebook.

**[SEE WORKING EXAMPLES HERE](https://s.nari.co.za/2U)**

**Wacth my [Youtube Video](https://youtu.be/mAyTvCdh-QY)**

Comment: Please add the necessary steps to the answer instead of linking to an outside site. Thanks!

Comment: I've done that - sorry (still new to this platform)